# GC overhead limit exceeded running background task in version 5.5

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

I am running SonarQube 5.5 with the following wrapper config settings.

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=3
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

I am still getting the following stack trace, this project has run successfully with sonarqube 5.3.

```
2016.05.09 11:14:09 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute coverage measures | time=105ms
2016.05.09 11:14:09 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute comment measures | time=120ms
2016.05.09 11:14:14 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Copy custom measures | time=5667ms
2016.05.09 11:14:15 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute duplication measures | time=424ms
2016.05.09 11:14:26 ERROR [o.s.s.c.c.ComputeEngineContainerImpl] Cleanup of container failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2016.05.09 11:14:26 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVSWNiXkOySW07vtMalp
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:671) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Entities.escape(Entities.java:838) ~[commons-lang-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.java:620) ~[commons-lang-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.DuplicationDataMeasuresStep$DuplicationVisitor.appendDuplication(DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.java:129) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory adjustments must be made in `sonar.properties`:

- `sonar.web.javaOpts` (for Web Server JVM)
- `sonar.ce.javaOpts` (for Compute Engine JVM)
- `sonar.search.javaOpts` (for JVM running ElasticSearch).

In your case the memory exception occurs in a background task so it relates to Compute Engine (see [SonarQube architecture](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+and+Integration) for more insight).

Settings in `wrapper.conf` are not relevant here and should be left untouched (hence the `# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS` warning in the file).