# SonarQube 5.5 OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead

Tags: java, garbage-collection, sonarqube, out-of-memory, sonarqube-ops

we are experiencing out of memory problems since we've switch from Sonar 5.1.2 to 5.5.
Crashes append on any project when a high number are building at the same time (anlysis are launched from jenkins builds).

Here is the parameters we are using in sonar.properties right now :

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx5g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx2g -Xms256m -Xss512k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

We also tried to change, in wrapper.conf :

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory=64
```

But no success (we have just postponed the problem...).

We are using the following plugins :

```
- Generic Coverage v(1.2)
- Java (v3.14)
- Java Properties (v1.7)
```

Here is the log :

```
    2016.07.26 15:39:11 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company.ch6:ch6-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbd1Z8EyeHX1QURId
2016.07.26 15:39:15 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company.ch6:ch6-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbd1Z8EyeHX1QURId | time=4165ms
2016.07.26 15:39:15 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company:ch11-processus:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbiF_8EyeHX1QURIe
2016.07.26 15:39:25 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company:ch11-processus:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbiF_8EyeHX1QURIe | time=9236ms
2016.07.26 15:39:25 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company:ch9-passerelle:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbk4l8EyeHX1QURIf
2016.07.26 15:39:30 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company:ch9-passerelle:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbk4l8EyeHX1QURIf | time=4970ms
2016.07.26 15:39:30 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company.ch6.tests:sbao-test-composant:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbmKC8EyeHX1QURIg
2016.07.26 15:39:31 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company.ch6.tests:sbao-test-composant:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbmKC8EyeHX1QURIg | time=1529ms
2016.07.26 15:40:05 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company.ch8:ch8-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbw3J8EyeHX1QURIh
2016.07.26 15:40:26 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company.ch8:ch8-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnbw3J8EyeHX1QURIh | time=21174ms
2016.07.26 15:44:05 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company.ch10:d3s-test-composant:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYncrQx8EyeHX1QURIi
2016.07.26 15:44:06 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company.ch10:d3s-test-composant:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYncrQx8EyeHX1QURIi | time=1287ms
2016.07.26 15:44:50 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company:ch4-processus:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnc2jN8EyeHX1QURIj
2016.07.26 15:45:53 WARN   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1469525831719] [gc][young][14905][56] duration [1.5s], collections [1]/[2.4s], total [1.5s]/[4.6s], memory [122.1mb]->[118.9mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [11.7mb]->[179.4kb]/[399.4mb]}{[survivor] [8.5mb]->[8.5mb]/[49.8mb]}{[old] [101.8mb]->[110.2mb]/[1.5gb]}
2016.07.26 15:45:57 INFO   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1469525831719] [gc][young][14909][57] duration [983ms], collections [1]/[1s], total [983ms]/[5.6s], memory [181.5mb]->[121.4mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [62.7mb]->[585.6kb]/[399.4mb]}{[survivor] [8.5mb]->[7.7mb]/[49.8mb]}{[old] [110.2mb]->[113.1mb]/[1.5gb]}
2016.07.26 15:45:59 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company:ch4-processus:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnc2jN8EyeHX1QURIj | time=68757ms
2016.07.26 15:45:59 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=com.my.company:ch10-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnc96t8EyeHX1QURIk
2016.07.26 15:46:10 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.my.company:ch10-services:trunk | type=REPORT | id=AVYnc96t8EyeHX1QURIk | time=10828ms
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to java_pid14404.hprof ...
2016.07.26 15:53:19 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:53:19 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
Dump file is incomplete: file size limit
2016.07.26 15:53:49 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:54:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:19 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:54:22 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:30 ERROR web[rails]
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError (GC overhead limit exceeded):
  java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
  java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
  java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1933)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1841)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1870)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1870)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1870)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1870)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.canonicalize(RubyFile.java:1817)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.expandPathInternal(RubyFile.java:1689)
  org.jruby.RubyFile.expand_path(RubyFile.java:747)
  org.jruby.RubyFile$INVOKER$s$0$1$expand_path.call(RubyFile$INVOKER$s$0$1$expand_path.gen)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:665)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$loadable_constants_for_path_BC452D91945DF6134CA553621D72071673C6F3D32047724929.block_0$RUBY$__file__(gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:339)
  rubyjit$ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$loadable_constants_for_path_BC452D91945DF6134CA553621D72071673C6F3D32047724929$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$loadable_constants_for_path_BC452D91945DF6134CA553621D72071673C6F3D32047724929$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
  org.jruby.RubyArray.collect(RubyArray.java:2396)
  org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$collect.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$collect.gen)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
  rubyjit.ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$loadable_constants_for_path_BC452D91945DF6134CA553621D72071673C6F3D32047724929.__file__(gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:338)
  rubyjit.ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$loadable_constants_for_path_BC452D91945DF6134CA553621D72071673C6F3D32047724929.__file__(gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb)
  org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:42)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$load_file_A8656A21340412012D4D507BC3B6F6F9C152F6472047724929.__file__(gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb)
  rubyjit.ActiveSupport::Dependencies$$load_file_A8656A21340412012D4D507BC3B6F6F9C152F6472047724929.__file__(gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb)
  org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:42)


2016.07.26 15:54:45 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:49 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:54:49 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.07.26 15:54:57 INFO  web[jruby.rack] could not acquire application permit within 10.0 seconds (try increasing the pool size)
2016.07.26 15:54:57 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Jul 26 15:54:57 +0200 2016
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `clean_message' for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded:Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError) on line #7 of gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:
4:     in <%=h request.parameters['controller'].humanize %>Controller<% if request.parameters['action'] %>#<%=h request.parameters['action'] %><% end %>
5:   <% end %>
6: </h1>
7: <pre><%=h @exception.clean_message %></pre>
8:
9: <%= render :file => @rescues_path["rescues/_trace.erb"] %>
10:

    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:7
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:133:in `rescue_action_locally'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:152:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:73:in `rescue_action'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in `call_with_exception'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    config/environment.rb:67:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:43:in `run'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'


    On line #7 of gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb

    4:     in <%=h request.parameters['controller'].humanize %>Controller<% if request.parameters['action'] %>#<%=h request.parameters['action'] %><% end %>
    5:   <% end %>
    6: </h1>
    7: <pre><%=h @exception.clean_message %></pre>
    8:
    9: <%= render :file => @rescues_path["rescues/_trace.erb"] %>
    10:

    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:7
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:133:in `rescue_action_locally'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:152:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:73:in `rescue_action'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in `call_with_exception'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    config/environment.rb:67:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:43:in `run'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
2016.07.26 15:55:19 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:55:49 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [Q5cPR9JRR_KgtNW3DDvIbQ][sonar-1469525831719] free: 0b[0%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.07.26 15:55:49 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1469525831719] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.07.26 15:56:03 ERROR web[o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.newFixnumNode(RubyYaccLexer.java:149) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.getInteger(RubyYaccLexer.java:514) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.getNumberToken(RubyYaccLexer.java:2466) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.parseNumber(RubyYaccLexer.java:2454) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.yylex(RubyYaccLexer.java:1197) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer.nextToken(RubyYaccLexer.java:343) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.DefaultRubyParser.yyparse(DefaultRubyParser.java:1375) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.DefaultRubyParser.yyparse(DefaultRubyParser.java:1326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.DefaultRubyParser.parse(DefaultRubyParser.java:3964) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:114) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:84) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:76) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.parseEval(Ruby.java:2593) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalSimple(ASTInterpreter.java:219) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.evalUnder(RubyBasicObject.java:1761) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.specificEval(RubyBasicObject.java:1711) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.instance_eval(RubyBasicObject.java:2480) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.instance_eval(RubyKernel.java:2204) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$instance_eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$instance_eval.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrTwoOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:314) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::Route$$write_recognition!_3B26896D881D00988FD41EDAFBFC893DD5E6F06C390761764.__file__(/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:205) ~[na:na]
        at rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::Route$$write_recognition!_3B26896D881D00988FD41EDAFBFC893DD5E6F06C390761764.__file__(/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::Route$$freeze_4D86AEDDA0A080910D5E6<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.07.26 16:00:22 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/temp
2016.07.26 16:00:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2g -Xms256m -Xss512k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process7043198058075938351properties
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469541622600] version[1.7.5], pid[16898], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469541622600] initializing ...
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1469541622600] loaded [], sites []
2016.07.26 16:00:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1469541622600] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/home (/dev/mapper/vg00-home)]], net usable_space [3.8gb], net total_space [6.7gb], types [ext4]
2016.07.26 16:00:24 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.07.26 16:00:25 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469541622600] initialized
2016.07.26 16:00:25 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469541622600] starting ...
2016.07.26 16:00:25 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1469541622600] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2016.07.26 16:00:25 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1469541622600] sonarqube/HU9HGZ-GQoSkHIAS_iebcQ
2016.07.26 16:00:28 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1469541622600] new_master [sonar-1469541622600][HU9HGZ-GQoSkHIAS_iebcQ][dev-sonar-12.XXX.XXX][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1469541622600}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2016.07.26 16:00:28 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469541622600] started
2016.07.26 16:00:28 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1469541622600] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
2016.07.26 16:00:31 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.07.26 16:00:31 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx5g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process804571309099725230properties
2016.07.26 16:00:31 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.07.26 16:00:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5/web
2016.07.26 16:00:32 WARN  web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/sonar12/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to [/sonar12]
2016.07.26 16:00:32 WARN  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] WEB DEVELOPMENT MODE IS ENABLED - DO NOT USE FOR PRODUCTION USAGE
2016.07.26 16:00:32 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.07.26 16:00:32 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.07.26 16:00:33 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.5 / 5773a4aab0ef6c0de79d3038e82f8a051049d6d0
2016.07.26 16:00:33 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://172.16.255.117/sonar
2016.07.26 16:00:33 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /home/sonar/sonarqube-5.5
2016.07.26 16:00:34 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1469541622600] loaded [], sites []
2016.07.26 16:00:35 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.PluginInfo] Plugin [l10nfr] defines 'l10nen' as base plugin. This metadata can be removed from manifest of l10n plugins since version 5.2.
2016.07.26 16:00:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin French Pack / 1.13 / 75ee9eb6def89803c48e06a48d6c155b93e8e3f6
2016.07.26 16:00:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Generic Coverage / 1.2 / 72f32ef33a81af33f153d15260f4af9b4e15c486
2016.07.26 16:00:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.14 / ffdbf119fb535cf242719b86a09c9a4ce35ca378
2
```

Any idea of what's going wrong ?

Comment: `wrapper.java.maxmemory` is the number of *mega*bytes, so 64M is not much, try setting 2048 or something.

Comment: The default value is 3 and, apparently, we don't have to change this value at all, others parameters should be enough (as stated here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120986/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-running-background-task-in-version-5-5). I've just tried because we had no other idea ^^

Comment: For now, we have drastically increased memory and it take 12go now...

Comment: We are now at 15,8Go. I suspect a memory leak in sonarqube...

Comment: There is not much help to expect on SO for such question, imho. 1/ any memory leak will require investigations which can't be done remotely (such as analyzing heap dumps and thread dumps, configuring, attaching and analyzing the VM's behavior with a profiler, ...). 2/ you're are running SQ 5.5 when SQ 5.6 LTS has been out for while. You should first move to the latest supported version of SQ before asking for help. LTS most likely has fixes which might just solve your problem.

Comment: Sonarqube 5.6 – Jun. 3, 2016 : is it really "for while" ? Did you expect your customers to switch each month to a newer version, even if this new version have some very deep impacts on the build chain like switching to Java 8 ? I was hoping more support for a version just one digit before the last one, but ok... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this late, but might help someone :

Try to increase ***MaxPermSize***

I have these configurations under respective **JVM Options** (web/ce/Elastic search) of **sonar.properties** file :-

> sonar.web.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m /
>   sonar.ce.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m /
>   sonar.search.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

For me, it actually worked with '1024m', just because I had multiple modules in my project and just as a hint my server as well need same size for deployments.