# Sonar scanner slow after upgrade to 2.8

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm in the process of upgrading to sonar-scanner v2.5 -> v2.8.  I've had a couple issues, but right now the real issue is that the scan is taking a long time. I'm looking for some hits about what I could try to make things run faster - on 2.5 our scan took about 1 hour.

Here's what I've tried so far.

1 - When I upgraded, the the scanner didn't like the the existing `sonar.java.libraries` setting.  Particularly, it didn't seem to expand the wild cards in the library path. I worked around that by constructing the path explicitly. There are about 400 third-party libraries in our build.

2 - I tried  diminishing then eliminating duplicate detection, first via `sonar.cpd.java.miniumLines / miniumuTokens`, and then with `sonar.cpd.exclusions`.

3- I've also upgrade the sonar server 5.4 -> 5.6.6.  When I did that, the number of rules in our quality profile (basically SonarWay + FindBugs Security) jumped from 300 to about 1200 rules. I reset the quality profile.

We have a multi-module setup, with one large module that runs last (6400 classes or so). The last module seems to grind for a long time - I can see the analysis count seems to slow down as the module runs.

Any hints would be great.

Comment: 4- I disabled the Findbugs plugin (v3.4.4) in sonarqube and the analysis time dropped from over 24 hours to 112 minutes.  The analysis uploaded to the sonar server, but the compute engine failed with a GC Overhead error.

I have increased the memory for the compute engine based on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120986/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-running-background-task-in-version-5-5

It seems the issue is likely related to this:
https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/41

So I'll try to follow up over there.